# User that suggests the most edits for posts made by other users

Tags: support, suggested-edits, data-explorer

I'm looking for a way to select the user that suggests the most edits for posts made by others. I'm unsure of how to specify that in my query. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT (*) PostId, OwnerUserId
FROM SuggestedEdits
WHERE OwnerUserId is not null
GROUP BY OwnerUserId
ORDER BY PostId Desc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't suggest edits to your own posts; they are automatically applied. Therefore, you don't need to cross-check with the Posts table, and [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/760966/users-with-the-most-suggested-edits) should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 COUNT(*), OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
  FROM SuggestedEdits
  WHERE OwnerUserId IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY OwnerUserId
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881229) is the current record holder on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

As @Glorfindel already covered suggested edits (the edits that you make until you reach 2K) I switched to [the top 100 for all editors](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/760973). I left out the community user (as they get all anonymous edits on their account).

```sql
select top 100 
       count(*)
     , userid as [User Link]
from (
SELECT distinct
       revisionguid
     , UserId 
FROM posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
WHERE p.OwnerUserId <> ph.userid
and posthistorytypeid in ( 4,5,6)
and ph.userid > 0 -- exclude community
) as data
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY Count(*) Desc
```

To get the all time editors you can use the posthistory table which records edits in its posthistorytypes 4, 5 and 6 (body, title, tags). A single revision is indicated with the revisionguid and by joining with posts table we can determine if this is an edit by the owner or by someone else.

[marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302) is the winner on Stack Overflow.